# How to make System.out.println() shorter

Tags: java

Please advice on where can I find the lib in order to use the shorter expression of `System.out.println()` and where should I place that lib.

Comment: You want to use this only because the expression is shorter?

Comment: Yes, this is the only reason.

Comment: If you're going to add a library to your project just to shorten an expression, you've got your priorities out of order.

Comment: That's just my third day I started to learn Java, so I'm not really worried about priorities you just mentioned.

Comment: Than you are doing it wrong, trust me.

Comment: I feel like this needs the code-golf tag.

Comment: Using System.out is generally bad in a well designed application, so the answers don't really matter...

Comment: @ErickRobertson After 5 years I can also understand that :) It was my first question on SO. Time flies!

Comment: @Eugene Happy Anniversary!  Five years is a long time!

Answer (score 321, accepted):

## Logging libraries

You could use logging libraries instead of re-inventing the wheel. [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) for instance will provide methods for different messages like `info()`, `warn()` and `error()`.

## Homemade methods

or simply make a `println` method of your own and call it:

```
void println(Object line) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

println("Hello World");
```

## IDE keyboard shortcuts

**IntelliJ IDEA and NetBeans:**

you type `sout` then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, and it types `System.out.println()` for you, with the cursor in the right place.

**Eclipse:**

Type `syso` then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

**Other**

Find a "snippets" plugin for your favorite text editor/IDE

## Explore JVM languages

### Scala

```
println("Hello, World!")
```

### Groovy

```
println "Hello, World!"
```

### Jython

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

### JRuby

```
puts "Hello, World!"
```

### Clojure

```
(println "Hello, World!")
```

### Rhino

```
print('Hello, World!');
```

### Kotlin

```
println("Hello, World!")
```

Comment: Hm... I haven't treid NetBeans so far. Installed Eclipse. Might be I need to give it a try.

Comment: `import static System.out;` is a rare practice, and quite unnecessary in my opinion, and thus seeing `out.println` can cause confusion at least initially. Static import has more idiomatic usage, but this particular case isn't it.

Comment: +1 for Eclspe & Netbeans shortcuts.  I'm undecided about the static import.

Comment: In Eclipse you can change the `sysout` template in *Java > Editor > Templates*. You can even make it more shorter by replacing `sysout` by `so` or so :)

Comment: @BalusC Better idea -- `so` CTRL+SPACE opens Stack Overflow in a browser window and you stop coding

Comment: `sout` also works in IntelliJ IDEA (NetBeans probably copied it from them :) Anyway, good to mention that – the length of `System.out.println()` becomes irrelevant with it IMHO.

Comment: Why didn't you suggest static import for the `println` method? `import static System.out.println;`

Comment: you can even type syso in eclipse it is enough

Comment: isn't it static void println(){} instead of println(){}?

Comment: @adarshr Doesn't work because `out` is a field. You can import the field, but not methods on it.

Comment: I can't believe I've been typing it out every time all these years in IntelliJ when I could have just typed `sout` + tab!!!

Comment: Homemade method which contains void coulnt print out in System.out.println unless it has a return value..

Answer (score 28):

```
void p(String l){
System.out.println(l);
}
```

Shortest. Go for it.

Comment: +1, just because it's amusing to see Java win a code golf for a change. ;-)

Comment: Actually it's straight out of "Beginning Java Programming: The Object-Oriented Approach" here http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Java-Programming-The-Object-Oriented-Approach.productCd-1118739493,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html

Answer (score 16):

Java is a verbose language.

If you are only 3 days in, and this is already bothering you, maybe you'd be better off learning a different language like Scala:

```
scala> println("Hello World")
Hello World
```

In a loose sense, this would qualify as using a "library" to enable shorter expressions ;)

Comment: This is my 5th year in Java, am i still in time ?

Comment: Absolutely! Scala has a very gradual learning curve for java developers.

Comment: I am addicted to Clojure

Comment: Right, Java is a verbose language; asking yourself questions like the OP is a normal part of getting to know it.

Comment: I am addicted to Java.

Comment: I can't open my jar of spaghetti sauce, what to do ?

Comment: @Ced I would suggest posting either on [Lifehacks](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/) or [Cooking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) forums.

Comment: Verbose is also every explicit. That's the point of verbosity.

Answer (score 15):

Some interesting alternatives:

OPTION 1

```
PrintStream p = System.out;
p.println("hello");
```

OPTION 2

```
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
p.println("Hello");
```

Answer (score 11):

For **Intellij IDEA** type `sout` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

For **Eclipse** type `syso` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Your answer probably depends on an IDE. You might want to explain where exactly this shortcut works. Otherwise your answer doesn't really help anybody.

Comment: @defaultlocale Thanks. Yes, it's true. I added some specific info.

Answer (score 7):

Use log4j or JDK logging so you can just create a static logger in the class and call it like this:

```
LOG.info("foo")
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 :

```
    List<String> players = new ArrayList<>();
     players.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

As Bakkal explained, for the keyboard shortcuts, in `netbeans` you can go to tools->options->editor->code templates and add or edit your own shortcuts.

In `Eclipse` it's on templates.

Answer (score 1):

A minor point perhaps, but:

```
import static System.out;

public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        out.println("Hello!"); 
    }
}
```

...generated a compile time error. I corrected the error by editing the first line to read:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution for **BlueJ** is to edit the New Class template "stdclass.tmpl" in Program Files (x86)\BlueJ\lib\english\templates\newclass and add this method:

```
public static <T> void p(T s)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Or this other version:

```
public static void p(Object s)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

As for Eclipse I'm using the suggested shortcut `syso + <Ctrl> + <Space>` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
package some.useful.methods;

public class B {

    public static void p(Object s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

```
package first.java.lesson;

import static some.useful.methods.B.*;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        p("Hello!");

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using System.out.println() is bad practice (better use logging framework) -> you should not have many occurences in your code base. Using another method to simply shorten it does not seem a good option.

Comment: I'd disagree. If you have normal logging in place already, then using Sysout is a better way to distinguish between what you need to see at the moment. Also, using sysout is much faster, and if you do a lot of debugging every second counts.