# how do you shorten system.out.println in java

Tags: java

what is the absolute shortest possible shortcut to call System.out.println that makes it callable via the shortest possible number of characters (like print())

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

And in your code:

```
out.println("Foo");
```

Comment: Wow, you're right! Edited the answer to reflect my newfound learnings.

Comment: @minichate - you posted first so you get a +1. @Ed - why do you think it doesnt work? http://www.ideone.com/PlF7V

Comment: It didn't work.  S/he fixed it.  I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion like yours.

Comment: Don't take it personal, it's not like the revision history is open to everyone. Thanks for cleaning up your comment.

Comment: can we more shorten than that?

Comment: Why do we still have to use out when we already imported it?

Answer (score 11):

```
public static void print(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
```

Comment: And, of course, you could put _this_ in one class and use a static import on _it_.  I'd guess that's closest to what the OP wants.

Comment: Yeah I mean he could call it p(string) if he wants which is pretty darn short but unreadable.

Answer (score 8):

## *Eclipse* shortcut

In the [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), just type `syso` and then press `Ctrl+space`.

Answer (score 7):

## *NetBeans* shortcut

In the [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), type `sout` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

## *IntelliJ* shortcut

In the [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) IDE, do the same: Type `sout`, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Answer (score 6):

The shortest possible way would be to create a method with a short name. Something like:

```
public static void out(Object o){
    System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

Now, you only have to call out("foobar"); in order to print something to standard out.
The reason I used an object and the toString() method is so that and integer, for example, gets displayed properly.

Comment: This too works as expected. Passing only String and then printing might cause error if integer or other type of parameters are passed. Passing "Object" solved this issue. Great answer...

Answer (score 3):

Autohotkey.ahk:

```
#!o:: Send System.out.println("");{LEFT 3}
```

Then, press <kbd>WIN+ALT+O</kbd>.

Unfortunately, autohotkey only supports win32. :(

Comment: hehehe autohotkeys :P autoit, I'm guessing you hack online mmorpgs? (sorry if i'm being rude).

Comment: Very nice. Autohotkey also works fine for me on Win10. For linux, try [Autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey)?

Answer (score 0):

If it's for the purposes of logging/debugging the logic of your program? **The call that never happens.**

Unless you are writing a console driven application, refrain from using System.out and System.err directly.

If you need logging, use a logging framework (j.u.l, log4j, jcl, avalon, slf4j, logback, etc).
These allow for improved context specific information, improved granularity and configuration at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

To make it shortest you can write an another  function and use it,but typing syso and clicking CTRL+Space is the best way I think.You should get used to using shortcuts when coding in JAVA ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workable example of the answers on this page, and also the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320764/how-to-make-system-out-println-shorter). I'm not sure if any of these shortcuts is recommended for readable, reusable code.

```
import static java.lang.System.out; // only for method of minichate&Tim Cooper
import java.io.PrintWriter;// only for method of Stephan Paul

public class PrintExample{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        out.println("Typing of 7 characters saved!");
        p.pl("shortened System.out.println, 14 characters saved.");
        p.pl(77); // takes non-strings
        p.out(88); // also takes non-strings
        p.print("sorry, I only take strings!");
        //p.print(99); compilation error, int cannot be converted to String
        PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
        pr.println(33); // method of Stephan Paul
    }
}

class p{
    // using generics (Java 5.0 onwards), by carlos_lm
    public static <T> void pl (T obj){
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
    // method by Neji3971 & bakkal, seems to work for all objects
    public static void out(Object o){
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }
    // method by Jesus Ramos & rup. Only accepts strings!!
    public static void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try this

```
package com.company;

class Database {

    // SOP to print function
    public static void print(String inp) { 
        System.out.println(inp);
    }

    public static void print(int inp) {
        System.out.println(inp);
    }

    public static void print(double inp) {
        System.out.println(inp);
    }

    public static void print(float inp) {
        System.out.println(inp);
    }

    public static void print(boolean inp) {
        System.out.println(inp);
    }

    // SOPLN to printLN function

    public static void printLN(String inp) {
        System.out.println(inp);
    }

    public static void printLN(int inp) {
        System.out.println(inp);
    }

    public static void printLN(double inp) {
        System.out.println(inp);
    }

    public static void printLN(float inp) {
        System.out.println(inp);
    }

    public static void printLN(boolean inp) {
        System.out.println(inp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        printLN("Hello");
        printLN(1);
        printLN(2.123);
        printLN(2.2);
        printLN(false);
        printLN(1+2);
        int x = 323;
        int y = 342;
        int z = x+y;
        printLN(x+y);
        printLN(z);
        printLN("Hello" + z);
        printLN("You can print anything.");

    }
}
```